# Detecting whether an audio file has speech in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I don't have so much idea about audio detection and I just started learning it today and came across webrtcvad(this felt poorly documented :'( ) and LibROSA. The task I have to do is that given an audio file, (which can be empty or it can have noise but no speech), I have to detect whether it contains any speech. Any idea how I can give it a start?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a generic question. There are several possible solutions though:

1. Pass it to a speech to text recognition. If you got text, there's speech.
2. In a more audio analysis method, use a frequency filter that only checks the range for human voice.

EDIT: Here are some libraries for processing audio

1. librosa (https://github.com/librosa/librosa) - has lots of features but documentation makes it hard for beginners
2. pydub (https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) - easier to use compared to librosa but only has few features and represents audio differently from librosa (not easy to integrate with librosa)
3. spleeter (https://github.com/deezer/spleeter) - separates vocals and other instruments

Comment: I liked the second process, would you kindly elaborate more on which modules can be used for this?

Comment: In this method, you are "filtering out" sound that are outside the human frequency (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_frequency) though this is sometime inaccurate because some noice are within this range.  There are existing examples in librosa module but I believe they are not properly documented. There is this other library I used before that is very good at separating vocals called spleeter (https://github.com/deezer/spleeter)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be done through frequency analysis? If so, depending on if you're using a mp3 or wav, these are the 2 options I'm aware of:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html
- https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen

Answer (score 0):

The [`speechmetrics`](https://github.com/aliutkus/speechmetrics) package provides two measures of absolute speech quality, the MOSNet and the SRMR. You may pass your audio excerpt to those packages, check the returned qualities for silence/noise/speech and set thresholds accordingly.